# QT6 / C++ Reading from multiple QListWidgets to singular textEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qlistwidget, qtextedit, qmap

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2LN9y.png)
I'm trying to connect Items in ListWidgets to textEdit (Descr) so that when I click on item the correct descr. shows. I can move items with '->' button to 2nd List and correct descr. follows, I used Qmap as a container.
Problem is once an item jump to 2nd List (or you click item in 2nd List) and then you click item in the 1st List, that item now has a Descr. of item from 2nd List i.e "2" has descr. "three".
Happens when you switch selections between lists, if you switch selections within the same list - all is fine.
Every clicked() signal reads the same (QMap record):

```
type void MainWindow::on_ToDoList_itemClicked(QListWidgetItem *item)
{
    ui -> InProgressList -> clearSelection();
    ui -> DoneList -> clearSelection();
    QString buff = item -> text();
    ui -> textEdit -> setText(record.value(buff));
}here

// I think the problem might be here:
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    QListWidgetItem* check;
    if(ui -> ToDoList -> currentItem() != NULL) check = ui -> ToDoList -> currentItem();
    if(ui -> InProgressList -> currentItem() != NULL) check = ui -> ToDoList -> currentItem();
    if(ui -> DoneList -> currentItem() != NULL) check = ui -> ToDoList -> currentItem();
    QString title = check -> text();
    QString buff = ui -> textEdit -> toPlainText();
    record[title] = buff;
}
```

clearSelection() because when you would switch selections between Lists then previous item would still be "semi-selected"(grey coloring) so I whought maybe it's that, but it's not.
I think problem is probably with the ifs since its my idea to do it this way.
I don't think it's '->' button issue since it happens without using it as well.

Comment: Would you be able to provide all of the code related to this issue? I would like to test it.

Comment: https://file.io/xKpyO8wsAVri - its QT Widget App of course, this txt is mainwindow.cpp the default folders are unchaged (execpt mainwindow.h - all the includes necessary)

Comment: @Hi It seems that some UI elements are missing.